# Spring boot 4 controller error: The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Fournisseur,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Fournisseur)

Tags: spring, controller, repository, entity

I'am new with spring boot. I'am using Spring boot (4) data JPA and MySQL. The method findall worked fine for me for the class fournisseur but the save method wont work.
Here my class:

```
    package net.javaguides.springboot.model;
    
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name ="fournisseur")
    public class Fournisseur { 
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long ID;
        @Column(name="Name")
        private String Name;
        @Column(name="Address")
        private String Address;
        @Column(name="Phone")
        private long Phone;
         
        public Fournisseur() {
            
        }
        public Fournisseur(String name, String address, long phone) {
            super();
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            Phone = phone;
        }
        public long getID() {
            return ID;
        }
        public void setID(long iD) {
            this.ID = iD;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.Name = name;
        }
        public String getAddress() {
            return Address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.Address = address;
        }
        public long getPhone() {
            return Phone;
        }
        public void setPhone(long phone) {
            this.Phone = phone;
        }
         
    
    }
```

Here my Repository:

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Fournisseur;
@Repository 
public interface FournisseurRepository extends JpaRepository<Fournisseur,Long>  {
}
```

Here my controller:

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.FournisseurRepository;
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200",maxAge=3600)

@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class FournisseurController<Fournisseur, Fournisseurs> { 
    @Autowired 
    private FournisseurRepository fournisseurRepository;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ID;
    //get all employee
    @GetMapping("/fournisseurs")
    public java.util.List<net .javaguides.springboot.model.Fournisseur> getAllFournisseurs(){
        return  fournisseurRepository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("/fournisseurs")   
    public Fournisseur createFournisseur(@RequestBody Fournisseur fournisseur){
        return fournisseurRepository.save(fournisseur);
    }
}
```

When running the application and use postman to post data it returns the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-13T22:06:19.958+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThe method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Fournisseur,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Fournisseur)\n\r\n\tat net.javaguides.springboot.controller.FournisseurController.createFournisseur(FournisseurController.java:33)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\n",
    "message": "Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThe method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Fournisseur,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Fournisseur)\n",
    "path": "/api/v1/fournisseurs"
}
```

And the IDE returns the following:

```
23:06:03.283 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@33c8d704

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v2.6.1)[0;39m

[2m2021-12-13 23:06:03.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mn.j.springboot.StockApplication         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting StockApplication using Java 17 on DESKTOP-BNFECFD with PID 19252 (C:\STS\Stock\target\classes started by ACER in C:\STS\Stock)
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:03.538[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mn.j.springboot.StockApplication         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:03.573[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:03.573[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:03.966[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.001[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 29 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.374[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.380[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.381[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.433[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.433[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 860 ms
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.528[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.628[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.655[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.685[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.785[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:04.850[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.150[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.156[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.324[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.512[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m LiveReload server is running on port 35729
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.605[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:05.612[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mn.j.springboot.StockApplication         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started StockApplication in 2.323 seconds (JVM running for 3.142)
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:19.900[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:19.900[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:19.901[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
[2m2021-12-13 23:06:19.954[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19252[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Fournisseur,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Fournisseur)
] with root cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Fournisseur,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Fournisseur)

    at net.javaguides.springboot.controller.FournisseurController.createFournisseur(FournisseurController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

In the video am following for this example the same code worked. I did some researches and it is possible to create a custom save method, i tried it but always got the same result, in addition it is not recommended to do so. Is there any issue with my class??

Comment: Any help on this request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the controller create fournisseur  by:

```
    //Create Fournisseur
        @PostMapping("/fournisseurs")   
        public net.javaguides.springboot.model.Fournisseur  createFournisseur(@RequestBody net.javaguides.springboot.model.Fournisseur fournisseur){
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            net.javaguides.springboot.model.Fournisseur updateFournisseur = fournisseurRepository.save(fournisseur);
            return  fournisseurRepository.save(fournisseur);
        }
```

and it works :D